# How to write "sub" join in HQL?

Tags: hibernate

How to write this raw SQL as HQL

```
SELECT p.* from Parent p LEFT JOIN ( child c INNER JOIN subchild sc ON c.subchild_fk = sc.subchild_id ) ON p.child_fk = c.child_id
```

I've tryied this, but Im getting error in place of brackets

```
FROM Parent as p LEFT JOIN ( p.childFk as c inner join c.subchildFk )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HQL does not support join operation with bracket, so it will raise an error in your query. To accomplish your requirement, we need to reorder the join tables to combine them straightforwardly (change *left join* to *right join* to keep the same meaning). In addition, HQL syntax is a bit similar to SQL syntax, you can rewrite your query in HQL as:

```
SELECT p.* from child c INNER JOIN subchild sc ON c.subchild_fk = sc.subchild_id RIGHT JOIN Parent p ON p.child_fk = c.child_id
```